# Thunderbird calendar - events missing after upgrade

Tags: 20.04, thunderbird

My original problem was a blank Thunderbird window (see below) but now the **problem is with my Thunderbird calendar -- specifically, all my events are gone.**

Previously: my Thunderbird mail client began opening up almost entirely blank, as shown below. I can still click "Write" and successfully send messages, but I can't see any folders or messages in order to actually read my email.
I was running Thunderbird 102.3.3 (64-bit) under ubuntu-snap-build 1.0, on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (64-bit), and GNOME Version 3.36.8.
I tried enabling and disabling Hardware acceleration and restarting Thunderbird, but to no avail.Reverting to Thunderbird 102.3.1-2 via `snap revert thunderbird 259` had no effect.  **My (partial) solution:** going to https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/releases/  and then selecting the very latest (beta) version of Thunderbird, unpacking & installing it. I then ran "./thunderbird --ProfileManager" first to make sure that I was selecting my old user profile, and -- bang! -- I can now see all my emails, but I still cannot see my Lightning Calendar appointments.
Specifically, the version I'm now running is the Linux 64-bit version of 107.0b1: https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/releases/107.0b1/

So: partial success, but my **calendar is still empty**.  Suggestions?

Screenshot of initial problem (not of blank calendar):

[image: mostly-blank Thunderbird screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was just to **copy** a bunch of Thunderbird files from my other computer to this one (with the broken calendar). Specifically, I copied over to my broken installation the "prefs.js" file in my Thunderbird profile directory, and **all** files in the profiles "calendar-data" subdirectory.  Even though that old computer was running Thunderbird 102 and the new one is running 107beta, the calendar now loads successfully.